# vertical tab panel in ExtJs 4.2

Tags: extjs, tabs, extjs4.2, tabpanel

Is there a way a vertical tab panel can be created in ExtJs 4.2 using the existing tab panel. By setting the tab strip to 'left', the strip is docked to left of the panel but that's not what I wanted. Is it possible to have the tabs positioned one by one vertically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can get the result you are looking for by setting `tabPosition:'left'` on the tab panel.

I've created a [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5ie) for demonstration:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            tabPosition:'left',
            height:400,
            width:1000,

            items:[{
                title:'Item 1'
            },{
                title:'Item 2'
            }]
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can have the tab titles displayed horizontally instead of vertical ?

Comment: There may be, however, i'm not sure how to. Possibly post as a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys I had the same problem..
down you have my simple solution (Sass and extjs)

```
Ext.define('Navigator.view.TestView', {
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.*',
        'Ext.tab.*'
    ],
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.testView',
    cls:'verticaltab',
    tabBar: {
        width: 340,
        minTabWidth: 330,
        maxTabWidth: 330,
        height:20,
        orientation: 'vertical'
    },
    tabPosition: 'left',

    plain: true,
    items:[
        {
            title:'first',
            html:'first'
        },
        {
            title:'second',
            html:'second'
        }
    ]
});
```

//Sass file

```
.verticaltab {    
  .x-tab-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  .x-tab-button{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 2px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide demo code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) i spent many days to find it and saw you post answer it match what i looking for. Please help provide working example code

Answer (score 0):

Main is to add cls to the tabpanel component
    cls:'verticaltab'

then add tabbar property:

```
 tabBar: {
    width: 340,
    minTabWidth: 330,
    maxTabWidth: 330,
    height:20,
    orientation: 'vertical'
},
tabPosition: 'left',
```

And then just add

```
.verticaltab {    
  .x-tab-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  .x-tab-button{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 2px;
  }
}
```

Sass file can be in theme folder structure..
I think it is not working on Safari but you can upgrade Sass code to work.

If it to hard for you I will prepare Sencha Fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Just tack these onto the tabPanel

```
tabPosition: 'left',
tabRotation: 0
```

Example:
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#advanced-tabs

Sources:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#cfg-tabPosition
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#cfg-tabRotation

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since weeksdev already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.